# Java - Problemas con While que NO se ejecuta o se repite dos veces al comparar caracteres

Tags: java, bucles, while, operador

Tengo un problema al utilizar el ciclo while y do-while en JAVA, que, al utilizar una comparación de caracteres y no numérica no funciona y se ignora la condición, creando ciclos infinitos. Y que no se pueda salir del bucle.

Lo que se busca es un código para ingresar empleados indefinidamente hasta que se presione **n** o **N**. Pero agregar otro más si se coloca **S** o **s**. Y despues salga para hacer unos cálculos con los empleados

La condicion en el ciclo while es que (mientras entrada != 'N' || entrada != 'n') se ejecute el codigo dentro del bucle. Peron no lo hace. Ignora la condicion para salir.

Creando un bucle que se repite indefinidamente, pero sin colgar la ventana.

A dentro tiene una condición if (si entrada = 'S' || entrada == 's') agregar empleado a una lista.

- Cuando presiono s o S agrega un empleado. Si le doy s para agregar otro no lo agrega. Y vuelve a preguntar.
- Cuando presiono n o N, sigue con el bucle y me lo vuelve a preguntar. Debería salir del bucle.

Este es el código que tengo:

```java
do{
          System.out.println("¿Desea ingresar un empleado?");
          entrada = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);

            if (entrada == 'S' || entrada == 's'){

            Empleado empleado;

            System.out.println("Ingrese nombre:");
            String nombre = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Ingrese apellido:");
            String apellido = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Ingrese cedula:");
            String cedula = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Especifique año de ingreso:");
            int ingreso = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Ingrese categoria:");
            int categoria = sc.nextInt();

            empleado = new Empleado();

            empleado.setNombre(nombre);
            empleado.setApellido(apellido);
            empleado.setCedula(cedula);
            empleado.set_year(ingreso);
            empleado.setCategoria(categoria);

            empleados.add(empleado);
    }

}while(entrada == 'n'|| entrada == 'N');
```

Si deseo usar el ciclo while, me queda así:

```java
while (entrada != 'n' || entrada != 'N'){
      if(entrada=='s' || entrada == 'S'){
    //CREAR EMPLEADOS


    System.out.println("¿Desea ingresar otro empleado?");
          entrada = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> > Java - Problemas con While que NO se ejecuta o se repite dos veces al comparar caracteres

Si el usuario ingrese la letra `s`, la condición:

```java
if (entrada == 'S' || entrada == 's'){
```

Se cumplirá y ejecutará el código que tenga adentro, el problema radica cuando esta condición llegue a ejecutarse:

```java
}while(entrada == 'n'|| entrada == 'N');
```

Como la variable `entrada` vale `s`, la restricción nunca se cumplirá y tendrá como resultado un `false`, haciendo que el bucle `do-while` finalice y esto ocasionará que el usuario no pueda volver a pedir datos de otro empleado.

**Una posible solución** es cambiar la condición de salida del `do-while` a:

```java
entrada == 's' || entrada == 'S'
```

Entonces el código quedaría así:

```java
do
{
    System.out.println("¿Desea ingresar un empleado?");
    entrada = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);

    if (entrada == 'S' || entrada == 's')
    {
        //Código empleado...
    }

}while(entrada == 'S' || entrada == 's');
```

Este algoritmo lo que hará es hacer iteraciones de manera indefinida hasta que el usuario ingrese el caracter `n` o `N` (u otro caracter) y solo pedirá información para el empleado cuando el usuario presione `S` o `s`.

Para no escribir dos veces la misma condición, se podría hacer uso de una variable de tipo `boolean`.

**Ejemplo:**

```java
boolean exit;
do
{
    System.out.println("¿Desea ingresar un empleado?");
    entrada = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
    exit = (entrada == 'S' || entrada == 's');
    if (exit) //Equivale a if exit != false
    {
        //Código empleado...
    }
}while(exit); //Equivale a exit != false
```

También se podría comparar cadenas con el método `equals` y lograr mandarle un mensaje de error al usuario cuando ingrese un caracter que no sea `S/s` o `N/n`.

Código java:

```java
while(true)
{
    System.out.println("¿Desea ingresar un empleado?");
    entrada = sc.nextLine();

    if (entrada.equals("s") || entrada.equals("S"))
    {
        //Código empleado...
    }
    else if(entrada.equals("n") || entrada.equals("N"))
        //Rompemos el ciclo
        break;
    else //Si no ingresó las opciones de manera correcta
        System.out.println("Error: Opciones correctas -> (s o S), (n o N)");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Los strings en java no se pueden comparar con operadores lógicos, debes hacer uso de ciertos, "métodos", disculpa, ando aprendiendo a usar JAVA también. Espero te sirva este link: http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Comparar_cadenas_de_texto

Una pregunta, debes hacer uso obligatorio de caracteres para mantener vivo el ciclo o no? porque algo que podrías hacer es, envés de usar carácter, podrías usar números, y te ahorrarías todos esos problemas

```
while(ciclovive == 1){
    /*el ciclo sigue*/
}
```

Comment: En el código del OP no está comparando cadenas, sino un caracter.

Comment: También intente hacer eso, utilizar Strings en vez de char y usar el metodo entrada.equals("S"),  y !entrada.equals("N") para la negacion y tampoco me funcionaron, nuevamente al escribir S se agrega un empleado más, pero al escribir N no hace nada, solo repete el bucle, y debería salir

Comment: Si, las ordenes es que sean caracteres s o n, así que no puedo utilizar números para comparar